# Chrome Developer Tools, difference between objects

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome-devtools

In Chrome Developer tools, What is the difference between:

```
>[]
    > 0: Object
    > 1: Object
```

and

```
>[Object, Object]
    > 0: Object
    > 1: Object
```

I am trying to debug an Angular 1 App, I have 2 buttons that run the same set of code.  On one button click I get the first console display and my data is not displayed, if I press the other button, all works fine. The right arrows are black right triangles actually.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The only reason I can think of for the first output is that your code assigned to the array's prototype: `a=[]; a.__proto__[0]={}; a.__proto__[1]={}; a;` or via similar prototype manipulation.

Answer (score 1):

both are array of objects
and the thing with chrome console is that it shows latest value of array.
So 2nd time your array has 2 objects (and I am assuming you are consoling same array) so it gives current value of that array in first line. But when that array get printed on console it was empty thats why [] symbol but right now it has 2 objects thats why its showing two objects.

Comment: It is the same array, and both have 2 objects.  The difference is the caption Object, Object in the second.   I am isolating the issue, in the first the object is outside of the $http get function and the second is inside of that function.  I always have a hard time with that issue

Comment: I am having a hard time understanding your issue, can you update your question with the function of both function click? I already answered what those 2 console lines mean and to tell anything else I need to have a look at your button events